# Hosting a process in C#.Net form disables some process's buttons

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I am trying to host a .exe within my .net application (Mainly video viewing software) however certain applications do not allow me to use their menu's or some controls. Has anyone had this problem before or any idea of why it could be happening?

Here is my code to host the application:

```
    #region Methods/Consts for Embedding a Window
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowThreadProcessId", SetLastError = true,
         CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
         CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern long GetWindowThreadProcessId(long hWnd, long lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongA", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, long hWndInsertAfter, long x, long y, long cx, long cy, long wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const int SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x200;
    private const int SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x8;
    private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
    private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    private const int WS_EX_MDICHILD = 0x40;
    private const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x20;
    private const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x10;
    private const int SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
    private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
    private const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    private const int WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000;
    #endregion

    #region Variables
    private IntPtr hostedProcessHandle;
    private Process hostedProcess = null;
    private ProcessStartInfo hostedPSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
    #endregion

    //Helper method to start a process contained within the form
    private void HostProcess(string processPath)
    {
        //Start the process located at processPath
        hostedPSI.FileName = processPath;
        hostedPSI.Arguments = "";
        hostedPSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        hostedProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(hostedPSI);

        //Stop watch is used to calculate time out period.
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        //Loop to aquire application handle. Exit loop if the time out period is past.
        do
        {
            hostedProcessHandle = hostedProcess.MainWindowHandle;
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 10000) throw new TimeoutException();
        } while (hostedProcessHandle == new IntPtr(0));

        //Host the process in the forms panel.
        SetParent(hostedProcessHandle, this.panel1.Handle);
        SetWindowLong(hostedProcessHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE + WS_MAXIMIZE);
        MoveWindow(hostedProcessHandle, 10, 10, this.panel1.Width - 20, this.panel1.Height - 20, true);

    }

    private void CloseHostedProcess()
    {
        hostedProcess.Kill();
    }
```

Here is a screen shot of my test application hosting VLC, Some of the menu's and buttons as you can see are grayed out and not working:

[image]

This is not just a problem with VLC — I see this issue when hosting other applications too.

Just an update. If i right click on VLC -> Play -> Add and play a video back manually the menu bar works again. However the video controls at the bottom are still not working! They change color when rolled over but clicking them still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was experiencing problems seems to be because TeamViewer was running in the background. I am currently trying to find out why this causes me issues but stopping TeamViewer's process seems to rectify my problem.